# Force the read() method to read a minimum no of characters

Tags: java, telnet, bufferedreader, expect

I am trying to do telnet to a router with expect kind of implementation.

My code is as follows for the socket communication is as follows,

```
            server = "my-server-ip-domain-here";
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(server, 23), 10000);//Will wait for 10 seconds
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
            expectBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

My send implementation is as follows,

```
  public static void send(String cmd) {
        pw.print(cmd + "\r");
        pw.flush();
    }
```

My expect implementation is as follows,

```
  public static String expect(String expectString) {
        try {

            int c = 0;


            char[] buf = new char[4096];

            //Here c will return the no. of chars read 
            while ((c = br.read(buf)) != -1) {


                String tmp = "";

                //converting that char array to String
                for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                    //Printing that character
                    System.out.print(buf[i]);

                    tmp += buf[i];
                }



                expectBuffer.append(tmp).append(NEW_LINE);


                if (expectBuffer.toString().contains(expectString)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            String expBuff = expectBuffer.toString();
            expectBuffer.setLength(0);
//            System.out.println(expBuff);
            return expBuff;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return "";
        }

    }
```

The problem i am facing is the no. of characters read by `BufferedReader` each time.

i.e. Each time I have to send some commands to the router and that is also being read by `BufferedReader`.

For eg.

```
send ("commandABC");
expect(prompt);
send ("command-efg");
expect(prompt);
send ("commandHij");
expect(prompt);
```

Based on the commands I am sending, it will show some output. Whatever I am sending, that is also being read and unfortunately, it is getting printed in a separate manner.

Like as below.

```
com
mandABC

<command output here>

command-
efg

<command output here>

commandHij

<command output here>
```

As i pointed out above, only the commands, whichever I am sending are getting printed in separate manner.

I have checked the no. of char read at that time and found that it is ranging from 2-10.

That is why it is getting printed in that manner.

Is there anyway to restrict the read at least a minimum of 100 chars?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to wait until you've read a full line of text, try `bf.readLine()` (you'd need to make sure each command was terminated by '\n'
- If you want to make sure you've read a certain number of characters (say 100) before continuing processing, use a loop:

  ```
  char buffer[128];
  for (int charsRead = 0; charsRead < 100; ) {
      charsRead += bf.read(buffer, charsRead, (100 - charsRead));
  }
  ```

  Note the (verbosified) syntax for `bf.read()`:

  ```
  bf.read(buffer, offset_size, max_to_read)
  ```

  Passing `charsRead` as the offset size means each block of chars read will be stored right after the previously read ones. Passing `(100 - charsRead)` as `max_to_read` limits the total chars you read.

Source: API ref [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read(char[],%20int,%20int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)